# make only one subcategory to collapse in bootstrap and angular

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

i am using jquery and bootstrap, and i have a drop down which opens upon the click of the category. but i want only one category to expand at a time. if any other category is already expanded, then upon the click on some other category, the expanded category should collapse

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-3 col-sm-offset-0 col-sm-4">
        <div id="menu">
            <div class="panel list-group">
                <a href="" class="list-group-item" id="heading">
                    <strong>Browse By Categories</strong>
                </a>
                <div>
                    <a class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#AAA" data-parent="#menu">
                        AAA <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down pull-right"></span>
                    </a>
                    <div id="AAA" class="sublinks collapse">
                        <a class="list-group-item small">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span> aaaa
                        </a>
                        <a class="list-group-item small">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span> aaaa
                        </a>
                        <a class="list-group-item small">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span> aaaa
                        </a>
                        <a class="list-group-item small">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span> aaaa
                        </a>
                    </div>
                <a class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#BBB" data-parent="#menu">
                        BBB <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down pull-right"></span>
                    </a>
                    <div id="BBB" class="sublinks collapse">
                        <a class="list-group-item small">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span> aaaa
                        </a>
                        <a class="list-group-item small">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span> aaaa
                        </a>
                        <a class="list-group-item small">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span> aaaa
                        </a>
                        <a class="list-group-item small">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span> aaaa
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

i have attached the jsfiddle also, if possible, please fix it.

https://jsfiddle.net/dpmvvq25/3/

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need the accordion component, here is an example using bootstrap:
    http://jsfiddle.net/zessx/r6eaw/12/

```
function toggleChevron(e) {
$(e.target)
    .prev('.panel-heading')
    .find("i.indicator")
    .toggleClass('glyphicon-chevron-down glyphicon-chevron-up');
}
$('#accordion').on('hidden.bs.collapse', toggleChevron);
$('#accordion').on('shown.bs.collapse', toggleChevron);
```